# How to install SharePoint Foundation? Prerequisite installer doesn't work, and claims I don't have Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 even though I do

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, installation, windows-7

I've downloaded both SharePoint Foundation 2013 and SharePoint Foundation 2010 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=35488) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=24983) respectively, as well as SharePoint Foundation 2013 with SP1 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42039).

When trying to install any of them, I get the error

> Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s):
>
> This product requires Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 or above.

So I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

[image]

However, it still gives me the same error when I try to install.

[image]

So I tried `Install software prerequisites`. Which gave me the error:

> There was an error during installation. This tool does not support the current operating system.

This happened on both SharePoint 2013

[image]

and SharePoint 2010

[image]

So I checked the log file, and it says:

```
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Processor architecture is (9)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Common Startup
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - from the following registry location...
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - The value is... 
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Error: Startup task doesn't exist. This is not a continuation after a restart.
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Locating the following command line arguments file:
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - C:\Program Files (x86)\MSECache\SharePoint2010\PrerequisiteInstaller.Arguments.txt
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Error: This file does not exist
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Details of the current operating system: 
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Major version number of the operating system:  (6)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (1)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X1DB1=7601)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (1)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0X100=256)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Product type of the operating system: VER_NT_WORKSTATION
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Product type:  (0)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - OS type:  (3)
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Error: This tool supports Windows Server version 6.1 and version 6.2
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
2015-03-16 08:31:37 - Cannot retry
```

It says `Error: This tool supports Windows Server version 6 and version 6.1` before closing. So I checked what version I have.

And it's version 6.1...

[image]

And I'm out of ideas. How do I install SharePoint Foundation? I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise, with Server Version 6.1 (Build 7601: SP1).

Edit:

I tried following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/373724/SharePoint-Installation-on-Windows) tutorial as suggested by Waqas Sarwar MCSE, but after running:

```
 SharePointServer.exe /extract:d:\SharePointFiles
```

It said Installation of this package failed.

[image]

Comment: You said `So I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.` then how the system is still Windows 7?

Comment: What do you mean? Are they somehow incompatible?

Comment: Based on your question, you stated you installed Windows 2008 R2 SP1. If you install that then the version should show Windows 2008 instead of Windows 7.

Comment: Well I'd like to keep Windows 7. Is there a way I can install SharePoint Foundation without going back to Windows 2008?

Comment: So, now the problem is, you are not able to  install SharePoint 2010 Foundation prerequisite. Right?

Comment: In your post, you mention the requirement being Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, however according to your screenshot, you have installed SQL Server 2008 R2... Also, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 are two completely separate OS's. You can't 'install' Windows Server into Windows 7.

I suggest you grab a free Azure trial and try it there using a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to install the SharePoint foundation 2010 on Windows 7.
You have to follow the different method to install it.

pen the command prompt and execute the following command:

```
SharePointServer.exe /extract:d:\SharePointFiles
```

(Ensure that you are specifying the folder in which enough space is there)[image]

So now we are ready with the files in the specified folder.

Modify the config.xml

Locate the config.xml file from the folder SharePointFiles\Files\Setup

Add the following tag inside the configuration section:

Run the Setup.cmd file

Read here for more details:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/373724/SharePoint-Installation-on-Windows

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind, but if I can install SharePoint Foundation 2013, I'd prefer to do that. The only reason I tried 2010 is because the 2013 installer told me "This tool does not support the current operating system." But the 2010 had the same problem so it's not that.

Comment: 2013 is not supported on windows 7 or 8....but sp 2010 still works on win 7

Comment: SharePoint Designer 2013 works on Windows 7, Visual Studios 2013 works on Windows 7, Lync 2013 works on Windows 7, SQL Server 2014 works on Windows 7, and SharePoint Foundation 2013 doesn't even work on Windows 8..? That's bizarre... Okay, I'll try this for 2010.

Comment: I downloaded SharePoint Server 2010 I tried that. After running `SharePointServer.exe /extract:d:\SharePointFiles` and letting it run as an administrator, it just said `Installation of this package failed.`.

Comment: did you follow the blog step by step.

Comment: Sort of. I followed the first step and that's where it failed.

Comment: on file extraction you are getting that error?

Comment: I believe so. I ran the extract command and it gave that error, and no other files showed up in the directory.

Comment: couple of things, first check if file is blocked(right click properties and see if it is blocked)....if it is unlocked then i am thinking file is not complete downloaded...try to download on different pc and then try again

Comment: Re-downloaded it, it's completely downloaded and not blocked. Same problem. I also tried following this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44210/Installing-SharePoint-Server-on-Windows-x, but even after changing the config file it didn't install. Oh well.

Comment: Using the last process what problem it is showing now?

Comment: is Windows 7 a virtual machine? I think, it's always easier to install SharePoint on a virtual machine. This way, if something goes wrong - it won't be a big deal. If you are installing it on your home/work computer directly and something goes wrong you mess up your environment. What are you going to do if today you need SharePoint 2013 and tomorrow SharePoint 2016? Are you going to reinstall your entire OS because of it? And what if you need two versions of SharePoint? If you can - enable Hyper-V and create a virtual machine, install Windows Server 2012R2 or 2014 and install SharePoint 2013